# Expression must be modifiable c

Tags: c, void

I'm trying to exchange two values in an array of which I don't know the type, but whenever I try to exchange the elements, the editor throws the error "Expression must be modifiable" or something like this.

```
void exchange(void * base, int i1, int i2) {
    void * aux = base[i1];
    base[i1] = base[i2];
    base[i2] = aux;
}
```

And I can't figure how I can do this without error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't know the type, neither does the compiler, and it has no idea how many bytes to transfer when you read and write `base[i1]` and `base[i2]`.  Moreover, `void *` is totally the wrong type for your `aux` variable — it would need to have the type of the array element being transferred, not a pointer to that type.

Comment: To make this work, you're going to have to (a) pass in the size of the array element as a fourth argument, (b) allocate an array (or the equivalent) of the same size for your temporary variable, and probably (c) use `memmove`.

Comment: A `cpp` macro could do this: `#define EXCHANGE(_arr,_i1,_i2) do { __typeof__(_arr[0]) tmp = _arr[_i1]; _arr[_i1] = _arr[_i2]; _arr[_i2] = tmp; } while (0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how big each unknown-element of the array is.
In the code below, I made that another parameter called "width"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void exchange(void * base, int i1, int i2, size_t width) {
    uint8_t temp[width];
    memcpy(temp, ((uint8_t*)base)+i1*width, width);
    memcpy(((uint8_t*)base)+i1*width, ((uint8_t*)base)+i2*width, width);
    memcpy(((uint8_t*)base)+i2*width, temp, width);
}

int main(void) {
    int foo[] = {3, 4, 5};
    exchange(foo, 1, 2, sizeof(int));
    
    printf("%d %d %d\n", foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
3 5 4  //(The 4 and the 5 got swapped)
```

Comment: It would be safer to use `memmove` for at least the second of the three copies, in case the function is ever called to swap an element with itself (that is, with `i1 == i2`).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the type of the elements. Henceforth I can't use sizeof in the parameters

Comment: If you don't know the type, or even the width in bytes (without knowing the exact type), then you're screwed.  You must, at a minimum, know the size of each element of the array, because swapping two elements of a `int64_t[]` is very different from swapping two elements of a `int8_t[]`.

Comment: The function I'm trying to make is alike the qsort() function which sort the elements of a table with any type. Do you know how it works ?

Comment: Yes, `qsort` takes as a parameter the width of each element.  The documentation calls it the `size` parameter (param #3).  There's no way around it, without the `width` or `size` of each item, its impossible.  With the size, I've already described how it can be done.